# Can I have some tris in my model made up of quads?

Tags: mesh

Firstly, I dont have that much experience with blender or 3d modelling. Im making a character for a unity project and would like to know if my model should only be made up of quads or is it ok to have some tris in it as well.

I only ask because I've been ending up with a few tris when I'm near to completing the model.

Also what are some ways of converting tris to quads manually.  I have used the "tris to quads" option without success.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5538/how-do-i-convert-a-triangle-mesh-to-a-quads-one/5539#5539

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99369/i-thought-you-should-never-use-triangles/99381#99381 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-should-triangle-meshes-be-avoided-for-character-animation/2939#2939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity only struggles with N-gons, which are polygons made of 5 or more vertices, so you shouldn't have problems if you have some triangles in your model.

Comment: Thanks, I actually searched a lot online and couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: No problem, I didn't find it on the internet either, a videogame design teacher told me that.